# StackLayout two columns each taking half of the space

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to make two labels each taking 50% of the width of the parent (the StackLayout)
I tried with Fill, FillAndExpand, StartAndExpand on both Label's but it didn't work:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    <Label Text="BBBB" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a `Grid` instead.

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Label Text="BBBB" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

The two `*`s mean the columns will have the same width.  If you wanted the first column to be twice has big as the second, you could change the first width to `2*`.

You can also use `EndAndExpand` to have the text right-aligned

Comment: thanks. I was looking into understanding how to use StackLayout, I already knew about Grid. But I mark your response as a solution since I don't think it's possible with StackLayout

Comment: Yes I don't believe it's possible with a StackLayout alone. If you need to use one though, you can always put the grid inside a StackLayout

Comment: I don't understand why the StackLayout with FillAndExpand set on both the Labels doesn't work. Since I am using 'expand' it shouldn't it allocated 50% of the available space for each Label?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was asked last year. But I hope my answer will help other.

Actually with `StackLayout` you can get the center and cut in half. I love using `StackLayout` because it has it's own automatic sizing, if you put 3 `Views` in a `StackLayout.Children`, the `StackLayout` will divide these 3 columns at the same exact size.

Here's how I do it in C#:

```
Content = new StackLayout{
   Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal, //Set the StackLayout to start from left to the right
   HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand, //Expand the layout to full width and center it
   Children = {
      new Label{
         Text = "Test One"//you may add HorizontalOptions in here to if you want the text on the left or right
      },
      new Label{
         Text = "Text Two"
      }
   }
};
```

Here's how I do it in XAML:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
   <Label Text="Test One"></Label>
   <Label Text="Text Two"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

I hope this would answer the question on `StackLayout` :)

Answer (score -1):

The previous answer doesn't work for me, but what I did was:
Set the HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" in the StackLayout.
Set the WidthRequest of the children with a big number, like 1000.
Like this:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
   <Label WidthRequest="1000" Text="Label 1"/>
   <Label WidthRequest="1000" Text="Label 2"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Setting width like that a bad idea